# Create mysql compatible Date from variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a field set to type `date` in a mysql table. I get day, month and year from user and at the moment I have the values returned like this:

```
[start_dateMonth] => 08 //$stardMonth
[start_dateDay] => 7 //$startDay
[start_dateYear] => 2013 //$startYear
```

How can I convert this to a valid date that I can easily insert in the database?

This is my own code, but for some reasons the browser just shows a blank screen with no source code inside:

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, "$startYear-$startMonth-$startDay $startHour:$startMinutes:00");

echo $start;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the manual

Although MySQL tries to interpret values in several formats, date parts must always be given in year-month-day order (for example, '98-09-04'), rather than in the month-day-year or day-month-year orders commonly used elsewhere (for example, '09-04-98', '04-09-98')

.Dates containing two-digit year values are ambiguous because the century is unknown. MySQL interprets two-digit year values using these rules:Year values in the range 70-99 are converted to1970-1999.Year values in the range 00-69 are converted to2000-2069.

located here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html

or `date("Y-m-d")` if you want to generate with a php function

Answer (score 3):

The least ambiguous form is probably `2013-08-07` ... but other forms are possible. Consult the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: It is not only unambiguous, it's the [standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)!

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$startYear . '-' . $startMonth . '-' . $startDay
```

Be sure to check if the date is valid with [checkdate()](http://php.net/checkdate)

Comment: year-month-year ? I think you meant year-month-day

Answer (score 0):

MySQL accepts strings as dates, and as others have pointed out, use [ISO8601 dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) where possible.

```
$isodate = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (datecol) VALUES ('$isodate')";
```